# dimens.xml -> R not generating

Tags: android, eclipse

When I add the file *dimens.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_width">419</dimen>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_height">138</dimen>
</resources>
```

to my values folder, R will not be generated.
What is wrong?
The file is OK - the rest of the project to. Cleaning the project up in Eclipse won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why it Showing

Because there are some compile error (or bug?) regarding to the *xml* file in res, so R is not genetared .

So,basically just Add unit beside your dimen value Like `dp`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_width">419dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_height">138dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then rebuild and clean your project

Answer (score 1):

because you can't create dimens whiteout indicating that whether its a dip or sp or... if you want to create an integer value use:

```
<integer name="something">100</integer>
```

and if it has a unit put it..

```
<dimen name="width">100dip</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify an unit for your value, such `dp`. E.g

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_width">419dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="smart_eyeglass_controll_height">138dp</dimen>
</resources>
```